# Segmentation fault ( core dumped ) when editing a file?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, bison, yacc, ppm

I'm making a program with bison in ubuntu that edits a ppm file given the user input but I'm having a segmentation fault core dumped error and I cant seem to fix it, heres my code:

```
void ponto(int x, int y, char fname[100]){
  int r,g,b;
  int i,j;
  int col,row;
  int c = 255;

  FILE *myFile = fopen(fname, "r");
  if (myFile == NULL)
  {
    printf("Ficheiro nao existe");
  }
  else
    fscanf(myFile, "P3\n%d%d\n255\n ", &col, &row);

  fscanf(myFile,"%d %d %d\n ",&r,&g,&b );

  FILE *fout = fopen(fname,"w"); 

  fprintf(fout, "P3\n%d %d\n255\n",col,row);

  for (j = 0;j < col; )
  {
    for (i = 0;i < row; i++)
    {   
      if ( j == y -1 && i == x - 1)
      {
        fprintf(fout,"0 0 0 ");
      }
      else
        fprintf(fout,"%d %d %d  ",r,g,b );

    }
    fprintf(fout,"\n");
    j++;
  }
  fclose(fout);
}
```

and heres my yacc code:

```
%{ 
#include <stdio.h>
#include "defs.h"
#include "funcoes.h" 
Lista lista_variaveis = NULL; /* guarda o valor das variavaies definidas */ 
char * cfile = NULL; /* variavel currentfile para saber que ficheiro estamos a usar */
%}

%union { 
       int valor;
       RES resolucao;
       COR color;
       COOR cord;   
       char * fname;
       char * idvar;}

%type  <resolucao> resol
%type  <valor> num
%type  <color> rgb
%type  <valor> expr
%type  <cord>  coord

%token <idvar> IDVAR
%token <valor> INT
%token <fname> FNAME
%token SAIR NOVA ABRIR GUARDAR PONTO

%start s
%%
s     : comando
      ;
comando :  NOVA resol rgb ';'{makef($2.resx,$2.resy,$3.r,$3.g,$3.b);
                          cfile = "teste2.pnm";printf("%s",cfile); } comando                      
        |  ABRIR FNAME ';' {openf($2);cfile = $2};  comando 
        |  PONTO coord ';' {ponto($2.xx,$2.yy,cfile);} comando    
        |  GUARDAR               
        |  defvar ';' comando
        |  SAIR         {return 0; /*termina */ }
        ; 
coord : expr ',' expr { $$.xx = $1; $$.yy = $3;}
      ; 
resol : expr 'x' expr  { $$.resx = $1; $$.resy = $3;}     
      ;
rgb   : expr':'expr':'expr { $$.r = $1; $$.g = $3; $$.b = $5;}
      ;
num   : num '+' num { $$ = $1 + $3;} 
      | num '*' num { $$ = $1 * $3;}
      | INT         { $$ = $1;}
      ;  
expr  : num         { $$ = $1;}  
      | IDVAR       { $$ = valor_variavel(lista_variaveis, $1);} 
      ; 
defvar: IDVAR '=' num  { define_variavel(&lista_variaveis,$1,$3);} 
      ;

%%``
```

Comment: Please use a debugger to step through the code to tell us where the error occurrs.

Comment: My guess is that the file does not exist where the program is looking.  You check for NULL, but the `else` that follows only applies to the first `fscanf()`.  The second is called unconditionally, and if a NULL pointer is passed in, you could get a segfault.

Comment: Also, you are using the same file name of input and output, having both open at once.  At a minimum, that's not good practice.  Since I never tried it, I can't say what the behavior is, but I would not be surprised if the `fopen()` call to write results in failure, and a NULL pointer.  The pointer is not checked at all, and passed into `fprintf`()`.  If NULL, that could be another source of a crash.

Comment: In addition to what others have said, you need to check `fout` for `NULL` after `fout = fopen(...);`.

Comment: @donjuedo When you open a file for output, it truncates the file. But since he's not reading from the input stream after that, it shouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: I put brackets after the else to include everything and it works but now it says "ficheiro nao existe"( file doesnt exist), it seems the PONTO line cannot read from the cfile.

Comment: Please add `printf( "%s \n", fname );` before the first `fopen()` call, update the post to reflect that, and let us know what is printed.  Also, what is the full path to the executable (and name of the executable)?

Comment: it prints (null) and i run the program in the terminal, i go to the work directory and i execute those files, they are all in the same directory.

Comment: In your flex file, how do you assign a value to yylval in the rule which returns FNAME?

Comment: \"[a-zA-Z]+.pnm\"                             { yytext[strlen(yytext)-1] ='\0'; 
                                                         yylval.fname = &yytext[1]; 
                                                                 return FNAME; }

Comment: Its so weird, i can get the value in cfile from NOVA to ABRIR but it doesnt seem to pass on to PONTO and it reads null, but if i add a value in PONTO like cfile = "teste.pnm" he will indeed execute it correctly.

Comment: @ArthuriusMelvic: That is incorrect. You are not allowed to export the value of the `yytext` pointer, because it is pointing into a buffer internal to flex whose contents may change unpredictably. (In fact, flex might even reallocate the buffer, leaving you with a dangling pointer.) You *must* copy string data into your own memory buffer -- usually with something like strdup -- in order to pass it to bison. Since you don't do that, the value of the string pointed to by `yylval.fname` may have changed by the time you try to use it.

Comment: THAT FIXED IT, i put yylval.fnname = strdup(&yytext[1]) instead of yylval.fnname = &yytext[1]  and it works!! ty very much.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with that code.

First, as pointed out in several comments, the following code will inevitably segfault if the file to be opened doesn't exist:

```
if (myFile == NULL) {
  printf("Ficheiro nao existe");
}
else
  fscanf(myFile, "P3\n%d%d\n255\n ", &col, &row);
fscanf(myFile,"%d %d %d\n ",&r,&g,&b );
```

because the `if` statement only prevents the first `fscanf` from being called if `myFile` is `NULL`. You should insert a `return` after the error message (I also fixed the printf):

```
if (myFile == NULL) {
  fputs("Ficheiro nao existe\n", stderr);
  return;
}

fscanf(myFile, "P3\n%d%d\n255\n ", &col, &row);
fscanf(myFile,"%d %d %d\n ",&r,&g,&b );
```

---

Second, there is undoubtedly a problem in your flex file (verified in a discussion in the comments). If your flex file has an action like:

```
{ yylval.fname = yytext; }
```

then you are violating the contract with flex. You are not allowed to export the value of the `yytext` pointer, because it is pointing into a buffer internal to flex whose contents may change unpredictably. In fact, flex might even reallocate the buffer, leaving you with a dangling pointer.

You must copy string data into your own memory buffer -- usually with something like `strdup` -- in order to pass it to bison. If you don't do that, the value of the string pointed to by `yylval.fname` may have changed by the time you try to use it. That would obviously result in the file not being found (if you are lucky -- it could result in some other file being overwritten).

Don't forget to `free` the memory you `strdup` when you are finished with it.

This point also applies to `IDVAR`.

---

Third, it is possible for `ponto` to be called with `NULL` as its third (fname) argument. In your bison file, `cfile` is initialized to `NULL`, and then modified to `"teste2.pnm"` by a `NOVA` statement, or the the filename from the input by an `ABRIR` statement. But if neither of those statements is encountered before a `PONTO` statement, `cfile` will still be `NULL`. You should either check for that case, or initialize `cfile` to a valid string; otherwise, the `fopen` in `ponto()` will probably segfault.

---

Finally, your use of mid-rule actions in your `comando` productions is a bit eccentric. I gather the intention is to insist that the last statement by either `GUARDAR` or `SAIR`, but the use of `return 0` in the action for `SAIR` pretty well bypasses the parser's check that it is the last statement. So you might as well have written a more normal left-recursive program production:

```
s   : comando
    | s comando
comando
    : NOVA resol rgb ';'
    | ABRIR FNAME ';'
    | PONTO coord ';' 
    | defvar ';'
    | SAIR
    | GUARDAR
```

If you really want the parser to verify that the last statement must be one of those two, you could do this:

```
s   : comandos ultimo
comandos
    : comando
    | comandos comando
ultimo
    : SAIR
    | GUARDAR
commando
    : NOVA resol rgb ';'
    | ABRIR FNAME ';'
    | PONTO coord ';' 
    | defvar ';'
```